# Hide element after deleting with jQuery

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, hide

I'm new to jQuery environment and I'm trying to hide an element after deleting it, there is a snippet of my html markup:

```
<tr <?php echo "class='m<?=$id?>' " ?> >
    <td><?=$email['first_name'] ?></td>
    <td> <?= $email["email"] ?></td>
    <td>
        <button  onclick="deleteRow(<?= $email['id'] ?>);" > Click here </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and my jQuery function looks like :

```
function deleteRow(id) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.m'+id).hide();
    });

    var baseurl = "<?= Zend_Registry::get('config')->app->baseUrl ?>/contactlist/contactlist";
    $.ajax({
     //some other ajax ..
     //ajax code ...
    });
}
```

Comment: Hiding an element that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a page that deletes you element, and then on success hide your element or replace the div with data from this page... delete_your_element_here.php

```
  $("button[name='approve']").on('click', function() {
        var data = $(this).data();
              $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "delete_your_element_here.php",
                data: { key: data.ident, value: data.value ,id: data.deal_id}, //send your data here to be deleted here
                success: function(data){
                $('#div_to_be_replaced').html(data);//replace your div or hide the current div here
                }
         });
    });



 <button type="button" name="approve" data-ident="pdeal_deal_retail_value" style="width:90px;" data-value="<?php echo $row_rsGetDeal['deal_retail_value']; ?>"  data-deal_id="<?php echo $row_rsGetDeal['pdeal_deal_id']; ?>" class="button_blue_form">Approve</button>
```

get the values that you send like this `$_POST['key'], $_POST['value'], $_POST['id']`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the row from the document after successful deletion then execute the code to remove the element in the delete ajax call's success handler.

```
 function deleteRow(id) {
    ....
    ....
    $.ajax({
       ...
       ...
       success: function(){
          $('.m'+id).remove();//You can call remove instead of hide
       }
    });
 }
```